# PHP spl_autoload_register() doesn't find function

Tags: php, autoloader

This code:

```
<?php
namespace designblob;

function autoloader($class){
        include "wrappers/databaseWrapper.php";
}

spl_autoload_register('autoloader');    
?>
```

throws this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Function 'autoloader' not found (function 'autoloader' not found or invalid function name)' in /var/www/xxx/library/autoloader.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/xxx/library/autoloader.php(8): spl_autoload_register('autoloader') #1 /var/www/xxx/library/debug.php(19): require_once('/var/www/xxx...') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/xxxm/library/autoloader.php on line 8

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Because you didn't give your spl_autoload_register the namespace the function is in.

Answer (score 13):

```
spl_autoload_register('designblob\autoloader');
```